# PHP Division returns Floating Value

Tags: php, string, integer-overflow

I am developing a PHP caluclator and I need a clarificator or any other method to do the step which I did now. Below is my situation and solution which I developed.

Lets see I am MULTIPLYING two values A,B.

```
$a=1;
$b=9;
$c= $a * $b;
echo "Output : ".$c;
echo "<br>";
// Now dividing the Values by D.
$d=1111111111111;
$e= $c / $d;
echo "Output after Division : ".$e;
```

> Output after Division : 8.1000000000008E-12

I am sure, the output is not an integer return,its a floating value.

My problem begins here I want to inform the user that the output is a floating point not an exact integer

```
// So below I have made a logic to do it.
if (strpos($e,'E') !== false) {
    echo 'The returned output is an Floating Value: ';
}
```

My Question: Is there any other way to do it? not by checking the output contains the string `'E'`. Some thing like the internal PHP returns some vale that ahs to be catched here and show to the user.

Advice me if I am doing any thing wrong.! or is there any ways to do this?

Comment: A float value isn't a string: if ($e !== (integer) $e) { echo 'The returned output is an Floating Value: '; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check, that the value is close to integer, you can try this:

```
<?php
$tolerance = 1E-6;

$result =  8.1E-12 + 2;
if (($result % 1) < $tolerance)
{
    print "$result is close to integer ". (int) $result;
}
```

Prints:

```
2.0000000000081 is close to integer 2
```

Comment: in this case if I just get some floating value it returns float but i want is in rare case when we add large values alone.

Comment: @TomPHP When the value is not float, the function will return false. It doesn't return float, it returns true or false.

Comment: I don't want to check all the output as floating values,intimated only the values which exceed the integer limits to be indicated to users such output are shown above.. Output after Division : 8.1000000000008E-12

Comment: check my question, I have done a logic where if the output is not any actual output for dividing two integer value. When the output comes is float no issue but when the output come with float+cant define integer/float value we need to tell the user that the value sis floated value exceed the integer/float limit.. just like some output exceed int(32) in c programming. I think i am cleared my question again!

Comment: @TomPHP You mean, if the fractional part is less or equal, then precision for floating values, we can dump it as insignificant an write to the user, that it's an integer? Like dividing 1 over 1E12 is very close to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from beeing horrible code, I think the function you look for is

```
bool is_float ( mixed $var )
```

(http://wwwphp.net/manual/function.is-float.php)

EDIT: like so

```
if ($e % 1 !== 0) {
 echo 'The returned output is an Floating Value: ';
}
```

Comment: in this case if I just get some floating value it returns float but i want is in rare case when we add large values alone.

Comment: I dont want all the floating values to me intimated only the values which exceed the integer limits to be indicated to users such output are shown above..

Comment: Output after Division : 8.1000000000008E-12

Comment: ah, check if X % 1 === 0, (or fmod(X,1) === 0) which does X modulo 1 => gives the remainder of a /1 division. if its Zero you have a integer. (This is without guarantee as its php and from top of my head)

Comment: Its like doing a operation again with the output :(

Comment: modulo is cheap, and honestly in a dynamic typed language runtime-typechecking/inferring/guesstimating is what you have to do (well at least in PHP)